# Can someone help me figure out how to print the options in this dropdown?

Tags: python, selenium

I've been trying to use selenium so I can list the available size options in this webpage but I am having difficulty identifying the class element. Every time I use main-size-select-0, I get an error saying unable to locate element. I have even tried using xpath but it didn't work either.

Here is my code below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get("https://www.asos.com/nike/nike-air-max-95-logo-leather-trainers-in-dark-navy-orange/prd/20750072?colourwayid=60085113")
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("main-size-select-0"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main problems may be that your code is looking for the menu before it's fully loaded.  You can use `WebDriverWait` and `EC` to hold the code until the element is loaded, then proceed.  It doesn't matter too much how you find the element, I used xpath, but you can do whatever you want.  Once you get it the `.text` method returns everything you need.

I split the text on newline and eliminated anything out of stock as well as the first item in the list which is 'Please select'.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.asos.com/nike/nike-air-max-95-logo-leather-trainers-in-dark-navy-orange/prd/20750072?colourwayid=60085113")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-size-select-0"]')))
dd = driver.find_element_by_xpath( '//*[@id="main-size-select-0"]')

[x for x in dd.text.split('\n') if not any(w in x for w in ['Please','Not'])]
```

Output

```
['UK 6',
 'UK 7',
 'UK 7.5',
 'UK 8',
 'UK 8.5',
 'UK 9',
 'UK 9.5',
 'UK 10',
 'UK 10.5',
 'UK 11',
 'UK 12',
 'UK 13']
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

1. The items in the list are loaded a bit later than when the page loads.
   I'd place a time.sleep() or WebDriverWait after your driver.get([URL]).
2. To get a list of elements in the drop down, you'll want to set your xPath to the "option" tag under "main-size-select-0".
   For Chrome, that would be: //*[@id="main-size-select-0"]/option
   Access these using *driver.find_element**s**_by_xpath* which would return a list of all the items in the drop down list

To summarize...

```
...
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get("https://www.asos.com/nike/nike-air-max-95-logo-leather-trainers-in-dark-navy-orange/prd/20750072?colourwayid=60085113")
time.sleep(5)
select_list = Select(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="main-size-select-0"]/option"));
```

Note that the xPath generated there was done via Chrome. It might differ slightly for Firefox. Just ensure you don't access a particular item in the list i.e: //*[@id="main-size-select-0"]/option[0]